# how can I pass more than one parameter in invocable method without using flow

Tags: apex, process-builder, visual-workflow, invocable-method, invocablevariable

In my Process Builder, on creation of my custom Object Bank__c record, I want to pass two parameters(Ids, objectApIName) to InvocableMethod in Apex class, so I added this to my code,

```
public static List<Id> idList = new List<Id>();
public class Request{
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public List<Id> ids;
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public String objectAPIName;
}

@InvocableMethod
public static void mergeAccounts(Request[] requests) {
    String objectAPIName; // Object API Name
    for (Request mp : requests) {                
        idList.addAll(mp.ids);
        objectAPIName = mp.objectAPIName;
    }
      ---
      ---
}
```

But when I am trying to add "ids" variable with RecordId in Process Builder it is giving me this error
"The input parameter "ids" can accept multiple values, so the assigned value must be a flow variable with the isCollection property set to true."

Is there any way I can pass the RecordId's into my Apex class just from PB instead of also using Flow. Let me know.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You'd have to change the variable to `Id` instead of `List<Id>`.

Comment: Thanks Sfdxfox.. if I just add Id, can you suggest me how can I modify my code to add that Id into List<id> 
I want to add "public Id ids;" to  "public static List<Id> idList = new List<Id>();" this list?

Comment: @user62694 You would iterate through the Request array and get the ID values from each. This is how the bulkification works for the flow engine.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!!